# NDepend detect properties with can be automatic

Tags: ndepend

We have old code where people have written properties against custom private variables which could be turned into automatic properties (public Foo { get; set; }). How can i detect this?

Answer (score 1):

To write such a rule, you need to join corresponding property accessors and fields somehow. I can imagine two ways to proceed:

1. You can check which property getter/setter is reading/assigning which field (only one field)
2. You can define a pattern on names of fields and property (for example every fields name is prefixed with two characters,  **Foo** property corresponds to **m_Foo** field)

The first rule could look like:

```
// <Name>Use Automatic Property</Name>
warnif count > 0 
from t in Application.Types

from f in t.Fields
where !f.Name.Contains('<') // Eliminate generated by compiler fields

let getter = (from m in t.Methods
where m.IsPropertyGetter &&
      m.FieldsReadButNotAssigned.Contains(f) &&
      m.FieldsUsed.Count() == 1
select m)

let setter = (from m in t.Methods
where m.IsPropertySetter &&
      m.FieldsAssigned.Contains(f) &&
      m.FieldsUsed.Count() == 1
select m)

where getter.Count() > 0 || setter.Count() > 0

select new { f, getter, setter }
```

The second rule could look like:

```
// <Name>Use Automatic Property</Name>
warnif count > 0 
from t in Application.Types

from f in t.Fields
where !f.Name.Contains('<') // Eliminate generated by compiler fields

// Here we consider that field name is prefixed with two any characters
where f.Name.Length > 2
let name = f.Name.Substring(2, f.Name.Length -2)

let getter = (from m in t.Methods
where m.IsPropertyGetter &&
      m.SimpleName == "get_" + name
select m).SingleOrDefault()

let setter = (from m in t.Methods
where m.IsPropertySetter &&
      m.SimpleName == "set_" + name
select m).SingleOrDefault()

where getter != null || setter != null

select new { f, getter, setter }
```

While the second rules might miss some positive, the first rule will return many false positive. Maybe we could write a mix of the two (with a pattern on name like property name contains partially field name).

[image]